# Keep first occurrence while removing duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, case-sensitive

I need to remove case-sensitive duplicates keeping the first occurrence and maintaining the order of the sentence.
This need to be done on each row of a column.

```
Initial format:                                        How the output should look:
col_sentence                                                 col_sentence
paper Plastic aluminum paper                                 paper Plastic aluminum 
paper Plastic aluminum Paper                                 paper Plastic aluminum 
Paper tin glass tin PAPER                                    Paper tin glass 
Paper tin glass Paper-tin                                    Paper tin glass
```

Is this possible to be done with python? I've created a function which works and removes duplicates but only by converting in lower and changing the order witch, is not feasible in my case.

Comment: Can duplicates be anywhere in the Frame? or will they always been in sequential rows?

Comment: @HenryEcker No, not anywhere in the Frame, I need to remove duplicates considering each row separate

Comment: Are there any word separators other than "-" and " "?

Comment: @not_speshal There can be situations like this: Caran D'Ache tshirt Caran D Ache where it should remain Caran D'Ache tshirt

Comment: So how are you expecting the program to recognize that "D'Ache" is the same as "D Ache" i.e., the " " is not a word separator?

Comment: @not_speshal This is the reason for which I did not mentioned that in the description, this can be ignored and we can consider only "-" and " " as separators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only "-" and " " are the word separators in your columns, try this:

```
def uniqueList(row):
    words = row.split(" ")
    unique = words[0]
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() not in unique.lower():
            unique = unique + " " + w
    return unique

data["col_sentence"].str.replace("-", " ").apply(uniqueList)
```

Edit (incorporating @im0j's suggestion): To avoid partial matching of strings (example: matching `pap` with `paper`), change the function to the following:

```
def uniqueList_full(row):
    words = row.split(" ")
    unique = [words[0]]
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() not in [u.lower() for u in unique]:
            unique = unique + [w]
    return " ".join(unique)
```

Comment: @not_spechal Awesome, thk you so much to all of you but this helped me obtain the expected output (works even in this case Caran D'Ache)

Comment: Be careful that this solution changes `'substring sub'` to `'substring'` which might not be suitable for future visitors.

Comment: @im0j - Excellent observation! Edited to handle this :)

Comment: @not_speshal is there something that could be done for cases like this "Bright-Starts Teethe & Read - Bright Starts" where this should be the output "Bright-Starts Teethe & Read" ? Or for this: "3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne 3 Sprouts, 3Sprouts, Organizador
" for this output "3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne, Organizador" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "paper Plastic aluminum Paper"
set_string = list()
for s in string.split(' '):
    if s not in set_string:
        set_string.append(s)
    
string = ' '.join(set_string)
print(string)
#output paper Plastic aluminum Paper
```

Sample python program to keep 1 occurrence and remove others. You can create a function from this and apply it to every row/column.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Requires python 3.7+ to ensure ordering.

```py
import re

def unique_only(sentence):
    words = re.split('[\W]+', sentence)
    unique_words = {}
    for word in words:
        key = word.lower()
        if key not in unique_words:
            unique_words[key] = word
    words = unique_words.values()
    return ' '.join(words)

df.applymap(unique_only)
```

---

Example Input:

```
                   col_sentence
0  paper Plastic aluminum paper
1  paper Plastic aluminum Paper
2     Paper tin glass tin PAPER
3     Paper tin glass Paper-tin
```

Output:

```
             col_sentence
0  paper Plastic aluminum
1  paper Plastic aluminum
2         Paper tin glass
3         Paper tin glass
```

Answer (score 0):

Another would be to use OrderedDict

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col_sentence':['paper Plastic aluminum paper','paper Plastic aluminum Paper','Paper tin glass tin PAPER','Paper tin glass Paper-tin']})
df.col_sentence.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x.replace('-', ' ').split()))))
```

```
0          paper Plastic aluminum
1    paper Plastic aluminum Paper
2           Paper tin glass PAPER
3                 Paper tin glass
Name: col_sentence, dtype: object
```